# Is American Cherry wood flooring durable enough for a kitchen and living room?

Tags: hardwood-floor

We are wanting to replace the carpet in our living/dining room and the vinyl flooring in our kitchen with solid hardwood floor. It's about 500 square foot on a heated crawl space floor. We like the look of [Mirage's American Cherry](http://www.miragefloors.com/ENG/hardwood-floors-american-cherry-natural.php?prod=36) (It's on Mirage's spring sale), but we are concerned with how soft it is. We don't have any pets and we don't wear shoes in the house.

I am worried about how much it will wear out in say 5-10 years of average usage from daily living. I am also considering Santos Mahogany, but it is almost 50% more than the American Cherry right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cherry is definitely not a real soft wood, and not as hard as oak, but a fine choice. It has been popular for flooring and cabinets for quite some time. I looked at the link for the brand you are considering. This brand, as well as many others, come with a fantastic pre-finish that really helps protect the wood with minimal maintenance. I would not hesitate in using it for your application. As with any wood flooring in an area subject to accidental water spills, be sure to pick up any spills quickly and not let it sit.

Comment: What do you think about dents and dings? I can be a bit clumsy in the kitchen...

Comment: often the retailer will have samples. Take a piece and test it with a few sharp hits from various items to see how dent resistant it actually is. Running and pushing hard on the edge of a coil on the finish is a good test.  I actually think you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that out and unfortunately, I may be just too clumsy for this species. I am going to check out some Santos Mahogany